# can JPA and memcached be used simultaneously in a web application? how?

Tags: java, jpa, memcached, eclipselink

i am developing a web application and for Object relation mapping  i am using JPA.
My application frequently reads from DB.
to speed up the DB reads can i use memcached along with JPA? what's the machanism? 
i am using JPA with eclipselink, eclipse and weblogic.

Comment: Possible duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/q/2349837/887235

Answer (score 0):

Only place JPA and memcached will relate through an API I can think, if you are using hibernate, is caching. If you are using Hibernate you may configure memcached as your 2nd level cache provider by using the [hibernate-memcached](http://code.google.com/p/hibernate-memcached/) project. Though I believe there are better alternative than memcached if you are just planing to use it as a hibernate 2nd level cache.
Memcached is an in memory caching system which you may use as a db it self.